# Regex for match and retrieve values from separated number list

Tags: php, regex, separator

Got a number list with separator(s) like these (note: quotes not included):

```
"1"
"1$^20"
"23$^100$^250"
```

I watch to write a regex to match both syntax of numbers and separators and also return all numbers in list, the best try I can get  in PHP is this code segment:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)(?:\\$\\^){0,1}/", $s2, $n);
print_r($n);
```

but it returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
        )

)
```

What I need is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 20
)
```

or at least:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
        )
)
```

Comment: FYI, `{0,1}` can be written more simply as `?`.

Comment: I don't know that. You mean like this: /(\d+)(?:\$\^)?/ What does the single ? mean actually? Would you care to explain?

Comment: `?` means that the preceding element is optional, so it matches 0 or 1 of them.

Comment: I correct my question. I should use two slashes while using double quote or  change it to single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the first entry in your match array like this:

```
$s2 = "1$^20";
preg_match_all("/(\d+)(?:\$\^){0,1}/", $s2, $n);
print_r($n[0]);
// Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 )
```

Or drop the group and just extract the numbers like this:

```
$s2 = "1$^20";
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $s2, $n);
print_r($n); 
// Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) )
```

Another alternative might be to use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split):

```
$s2 = "1$^20";
$n = preg_split('/\$\^/', $s2);
print_r($n);
// Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 )
```

Comment: @Barmar OP gave two potential outputs. The first solution one matches the first output, second one matches the second output, just in case he is not able to control how that result array is used elsewhere in his application. But yes, they can be combined, as well.

Comment: Thanks! The 2nd one is quick answer which never comes into my mind. It knows the separator doesn't have number in it. Say, just for research purpose, what if the separator contains number, e.g."$1", given a list "234$1567$189", is it possbile to write a regex to do same thing in my question?

Comment: @ScottChu In that case I would probably use [`preg_split`](http://us1.php.net/preg_split) instead. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: @p.s.wg: Excuse my misunderstanding of preg_match_all. Your 1st expression answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this quesiton again. I know I need not only split them but also check the value syntax. And what if it's a text seprated list? ... Hmm... then a smart way comes into my mind as follows in PHP codes:

```
// Split and also check value validity of number separated list
$pattern1 = "/(\d+?)\\$\\^/";
$1 = "1^$23";
$s1 .= "$^"; // Always append one separator set
preg_match_all($pattern1, $s1, $matches);
```

Change \d to . will work for text separated list or number-text-mixed separated list, too.